# Is field-basis of integral elements an integral basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, integral-basis

Suppose we have a finite field extension $K = \mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ with basis $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}$ where all $\alpha^i$ are integral elements. Do they form an integral basis of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$?

Comment: No. Not even a strategic choice of $\alpha$ helps. See [Keith Conrad, *Rings of integers without a power basis*](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf).

Comment: As in the answers, "no", ... but, sometimes it's sufficient to know that, by free $\mathbb Z$-module ranks, you'd be off only by finite index, ... and only finitely-many primes divide the index, ... and, _locally_, almost everywhere you _would_ have an integral basis for the (local) integers. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Take for instance $\alpha = \sqrt 5$.

Even worse, there may not exist a suitable $\alpha$. This is the case for the   cubic field generated by a root of the polynomial $X^{3}-X^{2}-2X-8$, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_field).
For a discussion and a proof, see [Rings of integers without a power basis](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

Answer (score 3):

No, not at all. Take your proposed basis $\{1,\alpha,\cdots,
\alpha^{n-1}\}$, a field basis consisting of algebraic integers. Now look at $\{1,2\alpha,4\alpha^2,\cdots,2^{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\}$, equally a field basis consisting of powers of an algebraic integer.

But since the corresponding $\Bbb Z$-modules have the property that the smaller is of index $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ in the larger, the two discriminants differ by a factor equal to the square of this, namely $2^{n(n-1)}$. Yet two integral bases of the same field must have the same discriminant. So at the very least, the second basis is not an integral basis, contrary to your conjecture.